# Groups, cosets and determinates

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we have $G = GL_2(R)$, $H = SL_2(R)$ and $A \in G$ such that $\det A = 2$.
We have to prove that $AH$ is the set of **all** $2 \times 2$ matrices in G that have determinant 2.

Can we simply say, oke $AH = \{AB : B \in SL_2(R)\} = \{AB : \det B=1\} = \{C=AB : \det C = \det A \cdot \det B = 2\}$ or am I missing something?

Okey, I think I have only shown that AH is subset of a set which consists of $2 \times 2$ matrices with determinant 2. Now, I have to show that this set is subset of AH in order to prove the statement. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am a bit lost now. :)

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ has determinant $2$, then $B=A^{-1}X$ has determinant $1$ and $X=AB$, so $X\in AH$; conversely, if $B$ has determinant $1$, then $AB$ has determinant $2$.

Both inclusion have been proved.

Your idea is good, but badly expressed.